# How to set cron in cakephp in cpanel on linux server

Tags: cron, cakephp-3.0, cpanel

How do i set the cron command in Cpanel in Linux server i use this it works for me is there any proper way

```
wget http://www.vloghit.com/crons/send_mail
```

Comment: Is there some reason that the standard cPanel cron job module doesn't work here? Seems totally straight forward.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the full path for wget like `/usr/bin/wget` instead of just plain **wget**. Depending on the WHM server configuration the crons might be running as jailed so you might get an error stating that wget command was not found if you do not use the full path to the binary. You are also supposed to receive an email notification from that cron job. Are you geting it? I'm asking because in those email notifications you get also an error message that can help you to understand why the cron was not working.